# Python for sum operation by groupby, but exclude the non-numeric data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, sum

How to do a sum operation using groupby from csv file in python, but exclude some non-numeric data from that groupby? E.g. I have the csv file:

```
id  | filename                  | #Line_Changed
-----------------------------------------------
  1 | analyze/dir_list.txt      |            16
  2 | metrics/metrics1.csv      |            11
  3 | metrics/metrics2.csv      |            15
  4 | analyze/dir_list.txt      |    =>
  5 | metrics/metrics1.csv      |            11
  6 | metrics/metrics2.csv      |    bin
  7 | metrics/metrics2.csv      |             4
  8 | analyze/dir_list.txt      |             4
```

I want to groupby the column Filename and only calculate the sum of the rows with only numeric data, and excluding the non-numeric data. The result should look like this:

```
  filename                  | SUM #Line_Changed
 -----------------------------------------------
  analyze/dir_list.txt      |            20
  metrics/metrics1.csv      |            22
  metrics/metrics2.csv      |            19
```

What I've done so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('diffhistogram.csv')
by_fn = df.groupby('filename')
mydata = {}
for name in ['#line_changed']:
    mydata['SUM ' + name] = by_fn[name].sum()
output = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
print(output)
```

but the output assume the data in column "#line_changed" as string:

```
  filename                  | SUM #Line_Changed
 -----------------------------------------------
  analyze/dir_list.txt      |         16=>4
  metrics/metrics1.csv      |          1111
  metrics/metrics2.csv      |        15bin4
```

Is there a way I can specify which numeric data to include in the sum() operation and non-numeric data to exclude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric to `NaN`s, then `groupby` + `sum` omit this rows:

```
df = (pd.to_numeric(df['#Line_Changed'], errors='coerce')
       .groupby(df['filename'])
       .sum()
       .to_frame()
       .add_prefix('SUM ')
       .reset_index())

print (df)
               filename  SUM #Line_Changed
0  analyze/dir_list.txt               20.0
1  metrics/metrics1.csv               22.0
2  metrics/metrics2.csv               19.0
```

Or assign to new column which is used for `groupby`:

```
df['SUM #Line_Changed'] = pd.to_numeric(df['#Line_Changed'], errors='coerce')
df = df.groupby('filename', as_index=False)['SUM #Line_Changed'].sum()

print (df)
               filename  SUM #Line_Changed
0  analyze/dir_list.txt               20.0
1  metrics/metrics1.csv               22.0
2  metrics/metrics2.csv               19.0
```

**Detail**:

```
df['SUM #Line_Changed'] = pd.to_numeric(df['#Line_Changed'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
   id              filename #Line_Changed  SUM #Line_Changed
0   1  analyze/dir_list.txt            16               16.0
1   2  metrics/metrics1.csv            11               11.0
2   3  metrics/metrics2.csv            15               15.0
3   4  analyze/dir_list.txt            =>                NaN
4   5  metrics/metrics1.csv            11               11.0
5   6  metrics/metrics2.csv           bin                NaN
6   7  metrics/metrics2.csv             4                4.0
7   8  analyze/dir_list.txt             4                4.0
```

EDIT:

If want drop non numeric rows from original `DataFrame`:

```
df['#Line_Changed'] = pd.to_numeric(df['#Line_Changed'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['#Line_Changed'])
print (df)
   id              filename  #Line_Changed
0   1  analyze/dir_list.txt           16.0
1   2  metrics/metrics1.csv           11.0
2   3  metrics/metrics2.csv           15.0
4   5  metrics/metrics1.csv           11.0
6   7  metrics/metrics2.csv            4.0
7   8  analyze/dir_list.txt            4.0
```

Comment: That works well. It's very helpful. But how can I plot this dataframe in bar chart by excluding the NaN data? I tried to plot them, but the NaN data were shown in the graph.

Comment: @Yusuf - Do yo uwant plot column `SUM #Line_Changed` ? Then use `df = df.dropna(subset=['SUM #Line_Changed'])`